# Creating new arrays each iteration

Tags: javascript, loops

I possibly am looking at this incorrectly, but I'm trying to make a `tournament` bracket creator. You input names that are entered into an Object called `players` I only want each side of the bracket to have `four` players in it. So I thought the best course of action would be to find out how many `sides` i would have in the bracket, once I had that I could look over those sides and for each loop I could place players in those `sides` but I've run into a bit of a problem. I'm not sure how to dynamically create these `sides` each pass. I removed some of my bad code so you can see kind of the idea I have

```
const players = []


function Player(name, deck){
    this.name = name
    this.deck = deck
    this.points = 0
    this.id = players.length + 1 
}

function addPlayer(){
    let player = new Player (
        document.getElementById('name').value,
        document.getElementById('deck').value
    )
    //console.log(player)
    document.getElementById('name').value = ''
    document.getElementById('deck').value = ''
    players.push(player)
    logPlayers()
}

function logPlayers (){
    output = ''
    for (let index = 0; index < players.length; index++) {
        output += (index + 1) + ') ' + players[index].name + ' | ' + players[index].deck + '<br>'
    }
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output
}

function initGame(){
    game = ''
    let cube = []
    const four = Math.floor(players.length/4)
    //console.log(four)
    const remainder = four % 1
    for (let index = 0; index < four; index++) {
        
        for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            
            
        }
        
    }

}
```

My array `cube` is what I was gonna uses as my `sides` and `four` is how many of those `sides` I will have. I will loop over them, and inside that loop I'll ensure I only put 4 players into each, however I'm getting confused on how I will create different `cubes` each pass.

I hope I explained this correctly

Comment: Perhaps, show a example of the object you want to generate?

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial I added my entire code for the project currently. I just wanted to loop over and add ```players[j]``` to each `cube` until they reach a max of 4, then new `cube` is created to hold 4 more players. Once again I apologize if I'm not explaining it correctly

Comment: [['player1','player2','player3','player4'],['player5','player6','player7','player8']] ? You need to  be precise in what you want.

Comment: @someoneSpecial exactly what you just posted, a new array will be created after 4 have been inserted into the last

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let cube = []
const four = Math.ceil(players.length/4)
let playerIndex = 0;
for (let index = 0; index < four; index++) {
    
    for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        if (!cube[index]) {
            cube[index] = [];
        }
        
        cube[index].push(player[playerIndex])
        playerIndex++
    }
    
}
```

This could be what you want?

player[playerIndex] will be the individual player by their array index, assuming player is an array containing the players.

Comment: to expand on this, this is a solution to being able to fill up 1 cube with 4 entries, however what if i have 8 entries and after the 4th entry, I want a new cube to be made. So I have 2 arrays that have 4 entries in them

Comment: you already declare "four" as a const in your code, by dividing your players by 4.

Comment: const four = Math.floor(players.length/4) <--- you did this. If you have 8 players then "four" will be 2.

Comment: ahh sorry, u should have used ceil instead of floor. updated answer

Comment: it's giving me an undefined the for the ```cube[index]```

Comment: added a condition to check if It exist. codes updated.

Comment: I appreciate it!